# How to create a matcher that verifies an async callback is doing right thing?

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-test

I would like to create a matcher that takes async or non-async callback, sets up some listeners, invokes callback, verifies listeners received expected events, and then clean up listeners.

However, I see couple blockers:

1. The method `Matcher.matches` is sync
2. It seems expectLater is taking result of invocation, so matcher cannot configure listeners

Is it possible at all to create what I want?

Comment: You can utilize the expectAsync function along with expectLater to handle asynchronous events in a custom matcher.

Comment: How it will help me to set prerequisites, then invoke async callback, then verify results in sync Matcher.matches? Should I just use 'then' without awaiting in case of async method?

Comment: 'then' will not work, because I need to return bool result from `matches`, that depends on result of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a helper async method `events` that takes the callback as parameter, configures listeners, invokes callback, cleans up listeners, an returns the list of the collected events. And then matcher analyses the list synchronously:

```dart
await expectLater(
    await events(() async {...}), areInRightSequence,
);
```